# How to use a filter for many2one filed on form?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have 3 fields which in my module page.2 are for  product categories and 1 for product. The categories fields consist of different categories. Now I want to add filter so that what ever category I set in the field, only those product should list in the products field . It is a type of sorting or filtering. I dont have much idea of using filter in such a scenerio under form view. Here is my code.py:

```
class deg_form(osv.osv):
    _name = "deg.form"
    _columns = {
         'categ1':fields.many2one('product.category','Parent Category'),
         'categ2':fields.many2one('product.category','Child Category'),
         'my_products':fields.many2one('product.product','Products',size=64),

            }


deg_form()
```

and here is its xml:

```
<record id="mywin_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mywin.form</field>
            <field name="model">deg.form</field>          
            <field eval="7" name="priority"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="FORM DATA" version="7.0">

                     <h1>
                       <label for="categ1" string="Parent category"/>
                           <field name="categ1" />
                     </h1>

                     <h1>
                       <label for="categ2" string="Child category"/>
                           <field name="categ2" />
                     </h1>
<newline/>

                     <h1> 
                       <label for="my_products" string="Products" domain = "[('categ1','=',True)]"/> 
                           <field name="my_products"/> 
                     </h1>


                 <button name="show_product" string="SHOW PRODUCT" type="action"/>
                 </form>
             </field>
    </record>
```

please help me fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use domain filter in py or xml as

```
domain = "[('categ_id','=',categ1)]"
```

Or

Overwrite def search method of product.product and pass categ field as parameter

```
def search(self, cr, uid, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None, count=False):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if context and context.get('search_default_categ_id', False):
        args.append((('categ_id', '=', context['categ_id'])))
    return super(product_product, self).search(cr, uid, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, context=context,count=count)
```

For Parent child relation of product category use this domain filter in py or xml
(categ2)

```
domain = "[('parent_id','=',categ1)]"
```

Comment: thanks this worked. do you have any idea to set a route in openerp so that when we login , the first page we see is our module. ?

Comment: hi arsalan, a simple way to do that, is to put the root's menu (if there is one for your module) sequence as low as possible, so that it is on the first position of all root menues (Messaging is default left root menu)